# How do I configure gitlab CI jobs to run on protected branches only?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to configure a gitlab CI job to run only on the restricted branches, but I cannot find an `only` directive to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Gitlab 11.11 you can check this accessing the environment variable `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED`

```
only:
    variables:
        - $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED
```

Reference:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced

Comment: I believe that this should use `$CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` instead of `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED`. source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#supported-syntax

Comment: Even with the suggestion above, this is still incorrect. The correct solution is sufficiently different that I will post my own answer.

Answer (score 32):

`rules:if` should be used.

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
```

`only:variables:` [has been deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)

Comment: What is the purpose of the single quotes? In the manual such expressions are used without them.

Answer (score 13):

Using `only:variables:` combined with `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` seems to be a good solution to your problem, but the details are difficult to determine without experimentation.

The documentation of the [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference) `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` is a bit unclear.

```
If the job is running on a protected branch
```

I expected `CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED` to be set only if the branch is protected, but it appears that it is a boolean value instead. This means we should check for the string `"true"` rather than existence of the variable. See [variables -> supported syntax](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#supported-syntax), rule 1. Equality matching using a string.

Putting this together, I'd say a complete solution that clearly expresses your intentions would be:

```
only:
  refs:
    - branches
  variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
```

The `refs:branches` is required if you don't want the job to run on protected tags.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I suggested a different warning on the official documentation [MR 26491](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/26491) that should land soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a protected variable to your project (or group).
Assuming you have set a variable `PROTECTED` with an arbitrary value you can use

```
only:
    variables:
        - $PROTECTED
```

in your .gitlab-ci.yml to check if the variable is present (since protected variables are only passed on to protected branches).

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I was looking for something that was more built-in gitlab.  In other words: 'why do I need to add a useless variable do specify jobs that should run on protected branches only?'.  Nevertheless thanks for the tip.  I can accept this answer if there is no standard way to do this.