# gitlab-ci.yml run job only on protected branch

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I want to execute a job only on the protected branches, I looked at the doc and it doesn't seem possible. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901151/how-do-i-configure-gitlab-ci-jobs-to-run-on-protected-branches-only You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

A branch can protect with which people can push on it or which people can merge on it.
but you can create a copy from that branch and do your job on it and after that create a request for merge it with the main branch

first you can create a branch with following command

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch-name
```

and after you are done your task push it on the server with following command

```
$ git push -u (origin-name) new-branch-name
```

and now you can create a merge request on the server and ask the admin to merge it.